# How to avoid dividing by zero.

Tags: calculus, limits

I am a 1st yr. College student. My question is ::
Generally, while dealing with calculus problems ( differential equations, limits, integration ,etc.. ), we work with a large no. of transcendental and algebraic functions and expressions, each of them having specific domains and ranges. Thus in the course of the problem, we are supposed to check the validity of each and every step and ensure that the information regarding the domains is preserved.
Specifically, we should check that each and every division performed in the solution should be valid( with non zero denominator). However, while reading and searching through STANDARD TEXTS on calculus, I find that this practice is not EXPLICITLY followed, i.e. in the solution, blatantly expressions are divided to proceed through ( without justifying the division ). For e.g.
A step in the solution of a d.e. requires the division of a particular expression by ($\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}  -  6y^3+ 7$) to simplify and proceed on the solution path. 
What I observe( in texts, or in people solving) in such cases is that the division is carried forth without keeping the provision for the case when $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = 6y^3-7$. 
While doing problems I always try to check such cases which greatly reduces my speed in addition to the overburdening headache of keeping the list of exceptions.

Hence, even while solving simple differential equations or manipulating trigo expressions, I tend to take much more time, while others get exactly the same answers without the additional checks.

Should I continue with the checks or move on without them or only a few of them( e.g. checking the final answer with the initial conditions, constraints, etc. ).
I would be thankful for any clarification or suggestions to my problems.
Thanks for bearing with me in this obscure, long thing.

Comment: I have the same concerns too, but I think especially in ODE you can be a bit more relax during the steps (keeping in mind the restrictions) but check in the end that your solution works

Comment: In practice, whenever division by zero arises, you'd do a casework. In your example, you divide by $y' - 6y^3 + 7$, so you'd consider if the case of $y' = 6y^3-7$ is a solution or not. If it is, great, you found one solution, and then you proceed with the division to see if there are others. If it's not, again proceed with the division. It's quite similar to trivial example of solving $x^2-x = 0$. You might be tempted to divide by $x$, so you'd check if $x = 0$ is a solution. It happens to be so, so you write it down and continue with the division to get $x - 1 = 0$ to find the other solution.

Comment: Thanks for ur early reply dmtri. So, should we do this exception check in general ( barring ode, ode, etc) while manipulating mathematical expressions. The problem with it is that it reduces the freedom of the mind as we start fearing complex methods due to such checks

Comment: Thanks Ennar. Actually I am concerned when the complexity of the casework increases, it becomes hectic to continue the checks as they imply their results in the upcoming steps or on the whole solution.

Comment: If that bothers you, just make a note to go back later and check.   In Enmar's example, you say if $y'-6y^3+7\neq0,$ and work out what happens in that case.  Later, you have to check out what happens if it *is* $0$.  There's no getting around it in a situation like this.  If you don't do it, you might miss a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, please keep on worrying about checking all those special cases!

The regrettable fact that some textbook authors are sloppy (when solving separable ODEs, in particular) doesn't make it right.